# Python excluding zeros from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, raspberry-pi-zero

Actually I'm doing an Alarm Clock Project using pi zero. So now the problem when the code fetch data from MySQL that is alarm time, it's goes to if condition to compare with current time. It's actually not working because python fetch not taking zero Infront of time.
Example
The zero Infront it been excluded...
If (6:45:00 == 06:45:00) false

But it's doing great after 10:00:00.

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM alarm WHERE status = 1")
        
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
       
for x in myresult:
    days = x[3].split(",")
    days = filter(None, days)

    for i in days:
        if(i == day):
            a = str(x[2])
            print(type(a))
            #alarm = a.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            print("Today = " +str(x[0]))
            print(a)
            print(str(now))
            if(a==now):
                print("Alarm Rings")
                GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(20, GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
                GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: It is not clear what `now` is.

Comment: Why don't you just store times in the database with zero padding?

Comment: Little more explanation please

Comment: Put `06:45:00` in the database instead of `6:45:00`.

Comment: Inside database is 06:45:00 but only on python is 6:45:00... I also fetch data on PHP... PHP not doing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading zero from `now` before comparing:

```
if now[0] == '0':
    now = now[1:]
if a == now:
    # rest of the code
```

Comment: Is this will spoil when time is above 10:00:00? I think no

Comment: don't you see the `if` statement? It only removes the first character when it's `0`.